# How to enable Leading and Trailing Swipe with Drag and Drop UITableview Cell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to enable `Leading` and `Trailing` swipe with Long press tableview cell to `drag` and `drop` option using `Swift`. Here, I am using below code I can able to drag and drop it but can’t able to do long press also can't able to enable leading and trailing `swipe` at a time. Three things need to enable by default when app launched.

**Tableview Delegate**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Delete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            print("OK, marked as Delete")
            success(true)
        })
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .orange
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Edit", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            print("Update action ...")
            self.showaddMilestone()
            success(true)
        })
        modifyAction.image = UIImage(named: "edit")
        modifyAction.backgroundColor = .red
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
    }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let movedObject = self.milestoneTitles[sourceIndexPath.row]
        milestoneTitles.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        milestoneTitles.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        debugPrint("\(sourceIndexPath.row) => \(destinationIndexPath.row)")
        // To check for correctness enable: self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Did you used canEditRow method of tableView delegate? Try it.

Comment: @JayrajVala Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: ```func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}```

Comment: @JayrajVala I gave `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return indexPath.section == 3
    }` because I need to only edit section 3 cell but even leading and trailing swipe not working when enable drag and drop.

Comment: Does yourm leading and trailing actions get displayed or it doesnt even bother to display? or you just can not able to perform action after using leading and trailing?

Comment: @JayrajVala when drag and drop enabled only trailing working not working leading also it iOS showing red round button on left side.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in following way...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    //EDIT
    let actionEDIT =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
        //do stuff
        completionHandler(true)
    })
    actionEDIT.image = UIImage(named: "icn_edit")
    actionEDIT.backgroundColor = UIColor.UIColorFromHex(hex: "F7F7F7")

    //PDF
    let actionPDF =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
        //do stuff
        completionHandler(true)
    })
    actionPDF.image = UIImage(named: "icn_pdf")
    actionPDF.backgroundColor = UIColor.UIColorFromHex(hex: "F7F7F7")

    //SHARE
    let actionSHARE =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
        //do stuff
        completionHandler(true)
    })
    actionSHARE.image = UIImage(named: "icn_shareGreen")
    actionSHARE.backgroundColor = UIColor.UIColorFromHex(hex: "F7F7F7")

    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [actionSHARE,actionPDF,actionEDIT])

    return configuration
}
```

// leftAction Leading

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let leftAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Edit", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("leftAction tapped")
        success(true)
    })

    leftAction.image = UIImage(named: "")
    leftAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [leftAction])
}
```

Comment: What about Leading swipe. I need to enable leading, trailing and drag and drop at the same time when app launched.

Comment: my question is leading and trailing swipe not working when drag and drop cell enabled time. Also, drag and drop need to prevent my section 3 it is allowing to place section three cell to another section. But need to restrict it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that works for me but I'm not sure if it's correct and will always work in future

```
final class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    private let data: [String] = [
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
        tableView.dragDelegate = self
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion ) in
            completion(true)
        }
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDragDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        return []
    }
}
```