# How to use Swipe Method with TableView editing

Tags: swift, tableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt method for Swipe. I also using drag and drop feature here.

Property tableview.editing is true in this condition. then i can't get callback of swipe.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

}
```

Comment: You mention swipe actions, tableview editing and drag and drop, but provide no example of how you are using them or how they relating to the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable Leading and Trailing Swipe with Drag and Drop UITableview Cell Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526339/how-to-enable-leading-and-trailing-swipe-with-drag-and-drop-uitableview-cell-swi)

Answer (score 0):

You must return an `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` object, like this example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        
    let firstAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "First Action", handler: { (action, view, done) in
        // Do stuff here
        done(true) // completion handler
    })
       
    let secondAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Second Action", handler: { (action, view, done) in
        // Do stuff here
        done(true) // completion handler
    })
        
    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [firstAction, secondAction])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true       
    return config
}
```